# Fast os for Raspberry Pi

Tags: archlinux, performance, c, c++

I'm creating a project with raspberry pi and I need an "os" which boots in a few seconds when the power is turned on. The os has to have the following features:

- audio driver (3.5mm)
- c/c++ running ability with sdl library(no X server)
- ability to mount usb (or an other way to transfer files)
- ability to install few little packages when needed (apt)

I've tried to use buildroot but I've found it too hard for me.

Comment: Do tell us a little more: what task needs to come up in this time frame?

Comment: What is a few seconds?  Less than of the order of 30 seconds then it can't be done.

Comment: You cannot have X up or even have a login or command prompt, but depending on what he needs he can have something coming up in a high priority init task way before 30 secs.

Comment: Well that's good.  If the OP's "few seconds" and "way before 30 secs" overlap the job is done!

Comment: You haven't bothered your self with search, haven't you? This question has been discussed more then once. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14763/how-to-improve-boot-time-for-raspberry-pi/14785#14785 http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7101/raspberry-pi-live-boot-or-read-only-distro/19830#19830 http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19495/is-there-a-console-only-no-gui-included-distro-under-1-gb/19502#19502 http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19358/how-do-i-improve-raspberry-pi-boot-up-time/19369#19369

Comment: He asked the same question 9h ago here:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=81548

Comment: Arduino boot loads in less than a second. Get that.

Answer (score 0):

The official OS raspbian will do, and if you use the new version / boot manager systemd it will be even faster.

But as mentioned this question is a duplicate [How to improve boot time for Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14763/how-to-improve-boot-time-for-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem and found that [Arch Linux](http://archlinuxarm.org) (and it was a first time for me - usually use Debian) to help me with boot time.